# Check location of current chromedriver

Tags: selenium, terminal, grep, selenium-chromedriver

I upgraded my chromedriver from v.2.35 to v.2.42. I have just downloaded v.2.42 and added to global path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/chromedriver
```

But when I enter in terminal `chromedriver`, I get

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881) on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed.
```

I cannot find that version of the driver in filesystem.

My question is **how to find out location of this old chromedriver**.

Selenium Tests still work, but I don't know which chromedriver version they are using. `pip3` and `pip` do not contain chromedriver.

I would like to find location of all chromedrivers on the system.

Comment: How is _check location of old chromedriver_ related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Comment: ```var driver = new ChromeDriver(DriverPath);``` where DriverPath is your env var or string path to the driver exe?

Answer (score 5):

Response for Windows:  (Note: the following works only when chromedriver can be located by path environment variable)

- command window (or IDE terminal) enter chromedriver (return)
- you should see something as stated above, 'Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881) on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed.'
- Do not close the command window or interrupt the chromedriver process you started
- open Task Manager and find process 'chromedriver'
- right click on 'chromedriver' and select 'open file location'

for myself the rogue chromedriver file was in bin of ruby installation.

Answer (score 1):

**To find out which chromedriver is launched when you run `chromedriver` command**:

1. Run chromedriver with ampersand at the end to put it in background and when it started, press Enter second time to return to command line:

   ```
   $ chromedriver&
   [1] 84039
   $ Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011) on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed.
   <press Enter again here>
   $
   ```
2. Previous command shows the PID of the process. Run `lsof` command for that PID to find the path of that process's executable. For example in my case PID was `84039`, so I will run:

   ```
   $ lsof -p 84039
   ```

   and the output will contain the line with the path to your chrome driver. For example for me it was:

   ```
   chromedri 84039 user  txt      REG                1,4 11917200     8691417 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
   ```

**To find all instances of chromedriver on a machine**

You need to remember that selenium (especially if launched from Jenkins or other CI tool), is launched in context of a specific user. So make sure when running the following command that you are

- either in a context of the same user as selenium
- or you are admin/root account which has access to private directories of all users.

Otherwise you may not find all the results. And then run `find` command. My preference to run it as root (with sudo):

```
sudo find / -type f -name chromedriver
```

The output will contain locations of all chromedrivers in the system, e.g.:

```
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver
```